# Converting table to picture directly

Tags: document-converter, screenshot, table

I know that I can draw a table in Word or Excel and take a screenshot. I just want to ask if there is any direct way to do that.

Comment: A direct way to draw a table in Word or Excel and take a screenshot? ;) Guess we need a few more details to provide good recommendations. May I suggest you take a look at [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"?](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/336/185) – and then [edit] your question to add some more details? Tha would also significantly improve your chances to really good and matching recommendations. Thanks!

Comment: Do you specifically require a *webapp*? Or any software that you can run on your computer is fine? Please edit the question title and tags to reflect this. I have added an answer about a software you can install in Windows, as I take the liberty to assume that you're most likely using Windows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your particular use case is too rarely needed to find any special software to automate the entire process of converting a table to an image. In fact, the top three results for a web search of *"table to image"* give instructions that are going to take you **longer** than taking a screenshot and saving it as an image.

However, you can speed up part of the process by using a screenshot software. I recommend [**Greenshot**](http://getgreenshot.org/).

> Mac OS X already provides [several screenshot shortcuts](http://guides.macrumors.com/Taking_Screenshots_in_Mac_OS_X). You can use <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>4</kbd> then select an area to get the same effect. The image will be saved to your desktop.

You must configure **Greenshot** to automatically save screenshots to a particular location.

[image: Screenshots showing settings to configure]

After the configuration, simply press the <kbd>Print Screen</kbd> key on your keyboard, then draw a box around the table. Greenshot will create the image file automatically.

**Tips:**

If the next table is fitting the same exact region (the box you drew), you can screenshot it even faster with <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Print Screen</kbd>.

You can also change the various keyboard shortcuts to your liking in the *General* tab.

Greenshot can also upload the image automatically to *Dropbox* or *Imgur*.

Comment: Great. Putting each table into each page of Word, and use the Reading mode will match with this solution.

Comment: @Ooker Thanks for accepting the solution. Mind editing your question title and tags to reflect that you just needed a software, not specifically a *webapp*? Thanks.

Comment: Well, I still want to have a webapp because of its convenience. But if there is no way to get the image without using a software, then I will accept this. Anyway, I will edit the title to make it more general.

Comment: Also, my most used OS is Linux :P

Comment: I don't know about out-of-the-box shortcuts in Linux (it will depend on your distro) but I'm sure you can get a convenient software for it.